# Take out innocence (phrase)

Tags: expressions, phrases

How do you correctly express this in English:

> Unsupervised internet browsing of a child can **take out their innocence** when they get exposed to pornography.

I believe this is a useful phrase. However, I don't know how to express it in English, should it be **corruption of the mind** or **take out innocence**. I am flummoxed.

Answer (score 1):

"Take out" is a mainly US slang, casual or informal expression meaning "kill" or "destroy". It is much used when discussing e.g. gun battles, etc. "Take away" or "destroy" would be more elegant.

Comment: Can I say "lose a child's innocence" as correctly expressed?

Comment: @John Arvin Yes, I think that's a good idea: Children may lose their innocence pretty quickly if they are allowed to browse the internet without supervision.

Comment: The questioner appears to be asking about an action 'losing' a child's innocence. That would be an incorrect use of the verb 'lose'.